# Page not loading when redirected, but when back button clicked displays the page for a sec and navigates to previous page

Tags: html, angular

I am working on Angular 2 and when I try to click a link, the page does not load but the loading bar goes on.
The data and the html is not shown in the page. When I click the back button to load the previous page, the Page which is to be redirected, loads or a sec and then goes back to the initial page. There is no errors shown in the Browse console and in the Server console.

Edit: I use a RouteComponent to route the page. The same link seems to work with other different screens, but this particular scene I see an issue where this needs to be fixed. When I try to debug, I could see that the component that I am able to load has the data inflow and doesn't break at any points to throw error.

```
  myRoutes : Routes = [
      { path: 'displayAuthentic/:authId', component: DisplayAuthenticComponent },
    ];
```

To Navigate when clicking on link,

```
 navigateToAuthDisplay(eventObj: any) {
           this.authId = eventObj.data.authId;
           this.router.navigate(['./displayAuthentic', this.authId]);
 }
```

Any pointers here to get through this..

Comment: Can you post some of your code? Are you driving the visibility of your screen with an *ngIf statement? If your driving it by waiting for data from the server, check out the network tab in the dev tools to make sure you're getting the correct data back.

Comment: Can we see your routing file?

Comment: Yes, I am showing the visibility through *ngIf. @thenolin

Comment: @Exterminator Not able to add Routing File, so showing the routing alone

Comment: add the whole file code

Comment: Not possible to show the whole file code.@Exterminator

Comment: @AshfaqueRifaye is your *ngIf statement getting fulfilled in order to show the screen? Sounds like the statement isn't getting the correct value in order to validate the *ngIf statement.

Answer (score 0):

regarding

> when I try to click a link, the page does not load but the loading bar goes on...

I am not sure because without your code it is difficult to figure out, but it seems to me that your route could be incorrectly configured. If the route in your link is `/myRoute`, make sure that you have in your route `app-routing.module.ts` in your routes variable you have the entry for the route

```
var routes = [
  {
    path: 'myRoute',
    component: MyRouteComponent
  },
...
```

And also make sure you used routerLink:

```
<a  routerLink="/myRoute"> link</a>
```

**EDIT**

Remember also to add this head in your index.html

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
 other css and jquery ...
</head>
```

Comment: I can't use a routerLink here in my case, as I am using an ag-grid to navigate the item when I select a data from a row. Instead, I declared a separate columnRenderer to that specific Column to make it redirect it.